# Getting a remote image to use with Codename One

Tags: image, codenameone

I am trying to retrieve a remote image to use it in a label. My code is the following:

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(100, 100);
ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage("http://www.example.com/logo-icono.ico",label, "cacheID-unique-identifier",dimension);
```

However, when I run the project, I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 3906
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:627)   at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:627)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternal(EncodedImage.java:270)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:245)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.drawImage(EncodedImage.java:433)
    at com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:505)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawComponent(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:1079)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawLabel(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:380)
    at com.codename1.ui.Label.paint(Label.java:335)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1029)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1003)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:978)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:903)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1023)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1003)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:978)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:903)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.paint(Form.java:2716)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1023)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1003)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:978)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:946)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1223)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1175)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty(CodenameOneImplementation.java:382)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.paintDirty(JavaSEPort.java:963)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:993)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:920)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:627)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ico files are windows specific and most devices don't support loading them. Only PNG & JPEG are guaranteed in devices.

I would also recommend using URLImage where applicable.

Comment: I have changed the .ico image for a valid .png, however, the error persists: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 3906. It seems there is a SIZE restriction. Is this corret?

Comment: If you used the same cache key then it will still bring the old image you can clear the storage.

Comment: Yes. By changing the cache key it worked. I did not know that in the development environment data like that key was preserved. ¿How can I programmatically clean the storage?

Comment: Answered this in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835949/optimizing-the-space-in-the-clients-storage-with-codenameone/25842185

Comment: Sometime image.getWidth() returns the following exception 
create image failed for the given image data of length
how to solve it ?

Comment: That would happen when the image is corrupt