# Optimizing the space in the client's storage with CodenameOne

Tags: image, storage, codenameone

In Codenameone I have the following code:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/advertisement.png";
String key = "goose_id-"+System.currentTimeMillis();
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(200, 200);
ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(url, label, key, dimension);
// Please note that every image will be assigned to 
// a storage key that begins with "goose_id_" string
```

In this way, every time I change the file advertisement.png in the server the user, in his device, will get a different image.

My only one concern is: After several changes of the file in the server, the user is going to have ALL those images in his device. Is this correct?

I want to know if this strategy will end up running out of space the users's device.

If this is true, How can I "clean" the storage objects that begins with "goose-id-" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everything gets written to storage for caching.

You can prefix the cache key with a `"toDelete_"` string then use the `Storage` class to loop over entries and delete them periodically. You can also do this in the `stop()` method of the main class to clear the storage when the app gets suspended.